# postfix calculator produces wrong values

Tags: java, int

In java, i'm trying to calculate things in postfix notation. However when i put anything in, it calculates them using ancii values in stead of int. So all my values are wrong. This is just the calculator snippet. I have the same code for the operands and the result at the end, but the operands are in ancii while the result comes out as an int.

```js
 public int evaluate() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (postfix==null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("IllegalStateException in evaluate().  Postfix expression not available yet.");
    }
    //valueStack is a stack of Integer objects:
    StackInterface valueStack=new StackReferenceBased();
    //variables for the operands:
    int operand1, operand2;
    //for each character ch in the string postfix
    for (int i=0; i<postfix.length(); i++) {
      char ch=postfix.charAt(i);
      switch (ch) {
        //if ch is an operator
        case '+':
         operand2 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
         operand1 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
          result = operand1+operand2;
          valueStack.push((int) result); 
          break;
        case '-':
         operand2 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
         operand1 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
         result = operand1-operand2;
            valueStack.push((int) result); 
          break;
        case '*':

         operand2 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
         operand1 = (Integer) valueStack.pop();
          result = operand1*operand2;
          valueStack.push((int) result);
          break;
        case '/':
         operand2 = Integer.parseInt((String) valueStack.pop());
         operand1 = Integer.parseInt((String) valueStack.pop());
         result = operand1/operand2;
            valueStack.push((int) result); 
          break;
        case '%':
         operand2 = Integer.parseInt((String) valueStack.pop());
         operand1 = Integer.parseInt((String) valueStack.pop());
         result = operand1%operand2;
            valueStack.push((int) result); 
          break;
        default: //ch is an operand
          valueStack.push((int) ch);
          break;
      }//end of switch
    }//end of for
    //at the end, the value of the expression will be on the top of the stack
    result=(Integer) valueStack.pop();
    return result;
  }//end of evaluatePostfix()
```

Comment: "antivalue"? What's that? `antivalue = !value`?

Comment: What is the shortest sequence which is incorrect?  What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger?  Why is some of the values `Integer` and some are `String`?  How is it supposed to know which one it is? Is this mean to handle numbers with more than one digits?

Comment: Marc B - Sorry meant ANCII value.

Comment: Peter - The casting of Integer and Stirng is leftover from trying to fix it. Doesn't make a difference. Basically what happens when i try to calculate something is that all of the operands are held in ANCII value and the calculated like those values are ints. So the result is correct, but for ANCII values instead of the original integers put in the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII (not ANCII) value for zero is 48
It appears that you are pushing the ASCII code of the digits onto your stack.
So, either subtract 48, or use Integer.parseInt(ch).